# LASTEXITCODE in powershell is alway 0

Tags: powershell

I am not a great powershell expert and I stumble on a problem that is undoubtedly trivial

When I run the following command in CMD (SAP related but it's not important)

`.\sapcontrol.exe -nr 00 -prot PIPE -function GetProcessList`

I get an exit code which may have different values depending on the state of the processes :

- 0  Last webmethod call successful
- 1  Last webmethod call failed, invalid parameter
- 2  StartWait, StopWait, WaitforStarted, WaitforStopped,
  RestartServiceWait timed out
- 3  GetProcessList succeeded, all processes running correctly
- 4  GetProcessList succeeded, all processes stopped

In powershell when i use

`Start-Process`  or `& cmd.exe / c`  my $LASTEXITCODE or $?  always returns 0 (probably to tell me that the command has been executed ... but that's not what I want ...)

how to get the equivalent of EXITCODES in powershell ?

thanks in advance

Comment: For `$LASTEXITCODE` to be populated, you need to invoke the executable directly, eg. `& .\sapcontrol.exe ...`. If you're using `Start-Process`, you'll have to check the `ExitCode` property on the `Process` object returned by `Start-Process`

Comment: why do you use `Start-Process` instead of running the exe file directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Start-Process` you can pass the argument `-PassThru` to get an object containing the process. Then, you can use the exit code property inside that object using `$YourProcess.ExitCode` :

```
$oProcess = Start-Process -Path $executablePath -ArgumentList $executableArguments -Wait -PassThru
$exitcode = $oProcess.ExitCode
```

More infos in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: `Start-Process` here is not necessary, because the OP calls the exe from cmd directly instead of `start sapcontrol.exe` in cmd

Comment: @phuclv of course, it's just one of the ways to do it